# How can I use Automate Batch Action of Adobe Photoshop to cut 5px for every image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing

I have thousands of pictures and almost all have different dimensions and I want to cut the bottom of every image for 5px using Canvas Size and then save it. How can I Automate Batch Process this?

For example if the image is 600 X 600 then I want to make it 600 X 595 and then save it. If the images had same dimensions then I could make an action and Batch Process it on the folder but the problem is almost every image has different dimensions

Comment: For that amount of pictures, I would go for ImageMagick - it is a bit of a hassle to set up, but with those amounts it will be worth it: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new action and hit record.

[image]

Go to canvas, select relative and type -5 into the height, set the crop to crop the bottom section.

[image]

Stop the the recording of the action.

Go to File > Automate > Batch

[image]

The latest saved action should be selected, if it's not, pick it. Run the action on the folder (pick the target folder) or opened files (I don't suggest this if you have thousands).

[image]

Save your files (if you didn't build save into your action).

*Side note: I'd recommend doing them in batches of 50 or so, otherwise your machine will be running for quite a while and it's going to run hot, this way you can let it have a cool down if it's getting too much.*

Comment: Your computer gets hot for processing images in mostly one thread? You should consider cleaning it with some canned air. I mean my main computer has been blasting the processor on the full for 2 days and its still not hot (well ok so its only got a 95%load average for 38hours straight)

Comment: @joojaa Mine is usually ok, but I like to be a little cautious. Plus it's a laptop, so if it does get hot, you know about it when it's on your legs.

Comment: I can't relate. My legs are always hot ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I already had found this solution just like you said but your explanation with images worth ups.

Comment: And in my action recording I also add save and close action so every image is resized, saved and closed. This way I batch proceesed 6750 images and yet my system didnt get hot at all.

Answer (score -1):

Here is steps to do it. It is not about crop image, but you can follow same steps to crop image as well.

You can refer below video guide.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQE2HQ8P-LI

1. Go to Menu > Window > Action
2. You can see we have all images of 500x500. "Converd" wil be destination folder where we will save images.
3. Create new set by click on folder icon in action widget. Give any name.
   4.Create new action. You can see set name, we just created in last step. Give a name to action here.Click on "Record" button.
4. You can see red circle, that means recording has been started. Now whatever you will do, will get recorded as action.
5. Menu > File > Open > choose file
6. Menu > Image > Image resize
7. Give a width. In this example it is 300px.
8. You can see, commands ( Open, Image size ), under choose action.
9. Now save the image for web device in jpeg format. Choose a destinatin folder.
10. Now close the file. You can see commands recorded.
11. Click on stop button, to stop action recording.
12. Now its time to repeat action, before that I removed file from destination folder.
13. Menu > File > Automate > Batch
14. Select the name of set and action, you created in last steps. Choose source files folder (files to be resized) and destination files folder (where resized files will be saved). Check all options according to you. And you are done. It will start resizing images and save in destinatoin foler automatically.