# How to save multiple files 300ppi in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, adobe-photoshop-elements

I am using Photoshop and I want to save multiple files at once like in 
export layers to files, my files are 326ppi and when I export'em all at once I get them with 72ppi (I know it's the screen resolution) I just don't know how it can be changed so I won't do this saving action for hours.
and if there's any script you can help me use 
I'd be glad for your help
thanks everyone

Comment: No. 72PPI is not any screen resolution. PPI resolution does not apply to screens.

Comment: What format are you exporting the images in? Why do you need them to be 300ppi?  An image at 72ppi can be exactly the same resolution as an image at 300ppi. Web browsers ignore PPI settings. PPI is not a measure of image quality.

Comment: 72 PPI is adobes way of saying "value not set", since they in their infinite wisdom didnt account for the possibility of a image with no set PPI value. Anyway sound like a job for imagemagi, Exiftool or some cmd XMP manipulator

Answer (score 1):

While what you said about ppi doesn't make a lot of sense, to answer your question:

1. Record [an Action](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html) that would change your document DPI to whatever you want and saves the image:

[image]

2. Then run it as [a Batch](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66292/how-can-i-use-automate-batch-action-of-adobe-photoshop-to-cut-5px-for-every-imag) (`File > Automate > Batch...`) on opened files or on a folder with your psds:

[image]

Comment: how can I solve the problem that it overwrites the previous png file ?

Comment: if you don't want your files to be replaced, in `Batch` window set `Destination` to your export folder.