# Is there a way to run Photoshop Actions and export an image on an input image from the command line?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation

I would like to convert thousands of images to pen and ink style like [this](https://elements.envato.com/pen-sketch-photoshop-action-UGCFS3). How can I automate this so I don't have to manually go into Photoshop for each image and apply the action and hit export? Can I do this from the command line or some programming language somehow?

Comment: Do you know "Javascript"??? You can use [File & Folder Object](https://extendscript.docsforadobe.dev/file-system-access/using-file-and-folder-objects.html "Folder object documentation") for accessing all the files via loops and then you can tell Photoshop to play action via `app.doAction()` command and then save those results via `document.saveAs()` command. Hope you find this useful :D

Comment: Have yoy tried [batch actions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66292/how-can-i-use-automate-batch-action-of-adobe-photoshop-to-cut-5px-for-every-imag?r=SearchResults)?

Comment: There's no need to do it from the command line or program anything. See [Processing Batch Files](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html).

Comment: @BillyKerr but what if you want to since your doing other stuff too?!? But yeah phptoshop actions can be called from commandline. As kan a COM and Applescript

Comment: @joojaa - Sure, fair enough.